# Cannot drag Firefox windows with title bar disabled using touch-screen

Tags: firefox, window, touchscreen

When I enable the title bar, I can drag a Firefox window with my touch screen. But when I disable it, I have to use the mouse or touchpad. I can drag other applications' windows normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag not by title bar but window content while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> key

Comment: Is there a way to enable this without having to hold alt?

Comment: Seems not, only title bar or alt is possible

Comment: Having to use a key, as in the Alt-key defeats the object of having a touchscreen for scenarios where there is no physical keyboard. As in use like an iPad, Android or Windows tablet. Tablet mode is not an edge case if we want Linux to be a viable alternative to other OSes, for real life end uses not just tech for tech sake, particularly with Windows 10 EOL and ethical landfill issues. If I'm out in the field, I really don't want to be struggling with UI when I'm half way up scaffolding on the side of a building.