Cannot move tabs around with touch screen in Firefox
I am using Kubuntu 24.04 (Wayland) on a laptop with touch screen.
With the touchpad/mouse I can move the tabs around, and drag a tab out of the Firefox window so that the tab gets its own window.
However, this cannot be down with the touch screen. When I tap on a tab, it gets selected. Nothing happens when I try to drag a tab.
How to drag/rearrange the tabs using touch screen?

Note: This is not a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1176544/124466
